# How to fetch mails from office365 account in MVC application which uses Office365 authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365

I am using following code for fetching emails from office 365 account in `MVC` application But it is not working, please help me in this issue.

```
    try
    {
           string token = Request.Params[0];
           string email = Request.Params["AUTH_USER"];
           OutlookServicesClient client = new  OutlookServicesClient(new Uri("https://outlook.office365.com/"),
                    async() =>
                    {
                        return token;
                    });
    var mailResults = await client.Me.Messages
                                  .Take(10)
                            .Select(m=>new{m.Subject,m.DateTimeReceived,m.From})
                            .ExecuteAsync();

     string content = "";

      foreach (var msg in mailResults.CurrentPage)
      {
          content += string.Format("Subject: {0}<br/>", msg.ToString());
      }
          return Content(content); 
  }

catch (Exception ex)
   {
     return Content(string.Format("ERROR retrieving messages: {0}",ex.Message));
   }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To better answer you question, make sure to state what is not working. Have you already tried to debug this to find a solution yourself?

Answer (score 0):

> I am using following code for fetching emails from office 365 account in MVC application But it is not working

Do you get any error message?

About using the Office 365 API in ASP.NET MVC application, I suggest you referencing the sample [O365-ASPNETMVC-Start](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start).

This sample uses the Office 365 APIs client libraries to demonstrate basic operations against the Calendar, Contacts, Mail, and Files (OneDrive for Business) service endpoints in Office 365 from a single-tenant ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

Download the project from GitHub

Open the solution in Visual Studio and "Add Connected Service", select "Office 365 API".

[image]

> Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

It could be the current user does not have sufficient permission to register an app on Azure AD.

To switch another user to log in, you can remove the previous one from connected users. Click the account on the top-right corner of Visual Studio 2015.

[image]

You may also get error "The specified account does not have access to the 'xxx.onmicrosoft.com' domain".

In this case, click "OK", then click "Cancel", retry "Add Connected Service" again.

For SQL Server 2014 LocalDB, you also need to change the default connection string.

Open web.config file, change the "DefaultConnection" as following:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ADALTokenCacheDb.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

If you don't want to use the Office API Tool, you can also [Manually register your app with Azure AD so it can access Office 365 APIs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/howto/add-common-consent-manually).

Comment: I tried Office365 APIs but i am having some errors which are-->

Comment: can you post the error message and the sample code that we can repro this issue?

Comment: I tried Office 365 APIs but i am having some errors which are-->

Error:Adding Office 365 APIs to the project failed: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

Comment: One more issue i am facing with this API. In Visual Studio 2015(Community version) -> connected service -> Office 365 API ->  Authentication against valid Office 365 account.  But there is no option for Login with a different account (Is it available only in paid versions and not in community version ?)

Comment: To switch another user to log in, you can remove the previous one from connected users, I've updated the details steps in my reply

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey for your reply, I have one more query please try to resolve.I implemented everything from ( https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start ) and every thing is ok exept AuthenticationHelper.cs . Following code is giving null value

Comment: DiscoveryClient discClient = new DiscoveryClient(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri,
async () =>
{
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId,
new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId,                                                                                                        SettingsHelper.ClientSecret),
new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
return authResult.AccessToken;
}); var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync(capabilityName);

Comment: And i dont know why but there is no row for 'Client Secret' in my web config file.
<appSettings>
<key="webpages:Version" value="......." />
<key="webpages:Enabled" value="......" />
<key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="......" />
<key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="....." />
<key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="....." />
<key="ida:FederationMetadataLocation" value="......l" />
<key="ida:Realm" value="......" />
<key="ida:AudienceUri" value="........" />
<key="ida:ClientID" value="......." />
<key="ida:Password" value="..........." />
<key="WkhtmltopdfPath" value="........." />
</appSettings>

Comment: according to your config file, it is for WS-Federation config, is it generated by the Office 365 API tool?

Comment: Yes, but not by Office 365. It is generated when we started to develop azure hosted website which uses office 365 authentication.

Comment: You should use the Office 365 Tool to connect to Office 365 service, it will auto add the client_id, client_secret and tenent_id to web.config

Comment: Could you please provide any tutorial or reference for this? Can i get ClientSecret from Azure management portal?

Comment: If you don't want to use the Office API Tool, you can also Manually register your app with Azure AD so it can access Office 365 APIs, updated the document in my reply.

Comment: We already manually registered app with Azure AD with required permissions of office365 APIs. But following code giving error  "Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken"

Comment: DiscoveryClient discClient = new DiscoveryClient(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri, async () => { var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId, new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.ClientSecret), new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId)); return authResult.AccessToken; }); var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync(capabilityName);

Comment: what's your setting of "ida:TenantId", if it is "common", please set it to your actual TenantId (guid)

Comment: I am using hard coded given code, please check and tell can that be a problem?
private static string _discoverySvcResourceId = "https://api.office.com/discovery/";
        private static string _discoverySvcEndpointUri = "https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/";

Comment: I made some changes and now its redirecting me for azure login but after successfully login it shows "Sorry, but we’re having trouble signing you in." and shows AADSTS50011: The reply address 'https://api.office.com/discovery/v1.0/me/' 
does not match the reply addresses configured for the application: fd642160-****-****-****-9a81db5c1d30. could you please help me on this.

Comment: @ashish, I'm not very clear the setting in your existing project, so I suggest that we can start from making the sample O365-ASPNETMVC-Start project on GitHub work by using Office 365 Tool firstly, after that, we can try to migrate the settings to your existing ASP.NET project.

Comment: Could you please find out what is SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri. Now i am getting Token but still facing one error "Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryFailedException: Exception of type 'Microsoft.Office365.Discovery.DiscoveryFailedException' was thrown."

Comment: could you please tell me what is end point uri for Office365 mail ?

Comment: @ashish, I'm working to write a sample which may help you to troubleshoot this issue, I'll post it here when I finished.

Comment: Thank you so much , my requirement is that i have to show my emails in one mvc application . i have to finish this issue in this week so please help me.

Comment: @ashish, here is the sample and I've tested in at my side, https://github.com/dream-365/OfficeDev-Samples/tree/master/samples/Office365DevQuickStart/AspNetMvc-with-O365

Comment: I created my app same as your given application. and according to your code i am facing "Failed to create outlook service client, please ensure you have capability to access mails". Please tell me how to resolve it? I gave only read mail permission in Azure AD , should i give all permissions?

Comment: @ashish, currently, the issue is on AcquireTokenSilently rather than "how to fetch a mail", if you have no questions about "how-to", I suggest you starting a new question to discuss "failed to acquire token silently", I'll keep looking into this issue.

Comment: as per your suggestion i am posting a new mail, please keep looking into this issue and help me. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36708812/failed-to-acquire-token-silently-call-method-acquiretoken

Comment: did you find any solution?